# can I keep company-purchased IP addresses when migrating to AWS (or other hosted service)

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, cloud-hosting

We currently run our own data center and want to migrate to AWS.
Because we send a lot of email, we want to retain the IP addresses that we have purchased (they have a good reputation with ISPs)
Will we be able to retain them as we migrate to AWS (or other hosting service)?
Based on what I have read, instances in AWS - whether EC2 or VPC - are assigned IP addresses from the Amazon pool, and thus we would not be able to retain ours. 
Is my information correct?

Comment: You should ask an/your amazon rep, not internet randos. If you've actually *purchased* the block from your RIR [eg: ARIN] they *might* be able to accommodate you. If you're leasing from your ISP, it's very unlikely.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to bring your IP to AWS. By default EC2 instances will be assigned a random IP that changes upon the instance being stopped, however you can optionally allocate an Elastic IP (EIP) which is permanently assigned to your account and enables you to have an instance with a fixed IP.

You might be able to ease the transition by proxying between your EIP and old IP, or using virtual private gateway during the migration.